# How to disable "dreams" system service

Tags: system, services, daydream

Some Android users often complain about some system service constantly executing, so just want to get rid of it *at any cost* to avoid battery drain. In my scenario it's `DreamManagerService` which is unimportant right now.

Since this is a system service (`service list | grep -i dream`) i can't find it in the process list (`ps -x | grep -i dream`), and interestingly also not seeing it in `init.rc` or similar. So my question is more about: **how to stop a system service?** (specifically on android)

EDIT: android version is 5.0.2 for the current question. It has been reported by other users that in android 6 apparently this service is visible and can be handled much better.

---

As a short introduction (bonus FYI), the so-called [DreamManagerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/DreamService.html) namely DayDreams or simply screensaver, makes sense for OLED screens which turn off black pixels, but some LCD IPS phones also allow this functionality (unreasonably).

Obviously I have already checked that the configuration is okay ([disable screensaver](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2818748)), but the service is still running and somehow preventing the CPU from sleeping, thus eating up the battery. This fact can be diagnosed by using `Wakelock Detector` app or similar one.

Comment: Nopes! This internal service is not listed no-were in the app -- I've already investigated with [disable service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice&hl=es),  additionally can't find any app named My Android Toolbox.  Did you try it yourself?  Internal service name is "dreams".

Comment: I  used [ROM toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro&hl=en) to freeze that *Basic Daydreams* on 6.0.1- you need to edit your question to mention android version and this is the other app, sorry wrong name earlier [My Android Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools&hl=en)

Comment: Thank you @beeshyams, i've been looking at your suggestion but apparently on Lolipop does not work (still hidden). I'll post my 'manual' answer later.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to kill whatever is running on Android is by using the Activity Manager, Package Manager, and deal with the Service Interface (see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html)).

However the `DreamManagerService` on my Lolipop is very tricky and it will complain it's not running at all (even if it is). So what I did was:

1. Enable the simple screensaver `Clock` and configure it to run only
   when docked. This makes sure it's working properly.
2. Execute with **root** the KillDreams.sh script, which kills everything relevant. As a bonus I run it automatically after every reboot using [Apps2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.pricealert.apps2sd.pro&hl=es).

   ```
   sleep 5
   echo Normal procedure for am...
   am stopservice dreams
   sleep 1
   echo Force procedure for am...
   am force-stop android.service.dreams
   am force-stop android.service.dreams.IDreamManager
   sleep 1
   echo Stop service...
   stop dreams
   echo Finished...
   ```

And voilà! It worked!
Currently my battery lasts nearly double, compared to having it run in the background.